# What is the difference between Transaction and Try Catch in SQL

Tags: sql, transactions

What is the difference between using transaction and Try catch in the case of uncommitted return ?
in other word in a transaction, if we return in the middle of SP without commit or rollback that table will be locked, I'm now wondering what happens to that table if I use try catch instead of begin transaction and End Transaction ?

Answer (score 2):

A transaction is an instruction to SQL to place a semaphore lock on tables contained with the transaction.   You can COMMIT the changes, updating the tables and releasing the lock or ROLLBACK, undoing the changes and releasing the lock.

`Try Catch`  by itself has not impact of table locking...   It is strictly error handling within the scope of a procedure.    What happens to the transaction is under your control...